# Get IP range of "Microsoft Corp" network provider

Tags: ip-address

I'd like to find the IP range of the "Microsoft Corp" network provider.

How can I find this out? So far I've only been able to find [this site](https://ipdb.at/isp/Microsoft_Corp) which has a list of ip addresses, not necessarily an explicit range.

There is a [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880179/how-do-ga-collect-network-providers-information), but doing a "whois `157.56.237.102`" on any whois site I've yet found doesn't give a range (have left a comment hoping for clarification)

Comment: I am concerned over what the motive of this question is. I can use my geo ip database, write a bit of code and extract a list from about a year ago but I am concerned what this list would be used for.

Comment: yes, I'm also curious.

Comment: To be specific. I have about 140 or so ip address ranges that I can extract. But I would want to make sure it is for a good purpose before I write code and post it publicly.

Comment: Thanks for the responses – this is a bit long winded, but I'm wanting to explore replicating the functionality of a google analytics View filter in a custom built javascript tracking application; the GA filter excludes certain bots from my View including the ones from the "Microsoft Corp" network provider. My idea was to find the IP range(s) that Google uses to ID "Microsoft Corp"

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides a downloadable CSV file with a pretty comprehensive list of their public IP address space.

As of August 2018, you can [download a copy of it directly from microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53602). (It's not immediately clear whether this link will change if they ever update this list. Just in case, you can also find it quickly by searching for "Microsoft Public IP Space" directly from the main Microsoft website.)

Comment: I wish Microsoft would separate ip4 from ip6 addresses and mostly, would give a direct link for download to automate processes.  At least, they provide a file; many do not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific range for Microsoft. They are a company, a big one, with a lot of power, but still a company. What they have, are small blocks of IPs here and there on the countries where they have servers. There are many IPs related to Microsoft in the world.

Comment: of course there is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, in general, as the company you target is a little too big to easily track all their public information.

Here is one way to tackle this that caters for a part of the problem (you will probably need to merge various answers to get a global picture)

Microsoft is a US company and as such when it needs IP addresses it needs to go to the relevant Regional Internet Registry, that is ARIN to request IPv4/IPv6 blocks. This is all publicly registered and queryable.

So if you go to
https://whois.arin.net/ui/advanced.jsp
and enter `Microsoft` in text field and select "Network" and "Name" the result page will list you 38 IPv4 blocks registered to a network having `Microsoft` in its name, you can click on any of them to get more information.

Of course this has many shortcomings:

- they can register IP blocks in other regions of the world, so you would need to do the same query for the other RIRs, like RIPE for Europe, etc.
  (go to https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/#/query?searchtext=microsoft#resultsSection to see an example of many other IP blocks)
- they could use IP blocks registered to others or do registrations using other names or depending on what you are exactly tracking just not using the IP addresses you think they are using

In part, you could do the same thing starting with their AS numbers and find out which IP blocks are announced by their AS.

And if you are thorough you should obviously take care of IPv6 addresses too.